# A Subscript Must be Between 1 and the Size of the Array

Tags: crystal-reports

i am receiving "A Subscript Must be Between 1 and the Size of the Array" for below code in crytal report. Please help!

```
'To Use Multiline if Basic Syntax was used
Shared Cust_Ids() As Number
Shared Page_No() As Number
Shared Cust_Ids2() As Number
Shared Page_No2() As Number
Local  m As Number
Local  i As Number 
Local  j As Number 
Local  Cnt As Number 
j=1
i=1
Cnt=Count({CL_Index_Page_ttx.Customer_ID})  
For i=1 To Cnt  
    If i <=1000 Then
        If Cust_Ids(i) - {CL_Index_Page_ttx.Customer_ID} = 0 Then
           m = Page_No(i)
           i=Cnt+1
        End If
    Else
        If Cust_Ids2(j) - {CL_Index_Page_ttx.Customer_ID} = 0 Then
           m = Page_No2(j)
          i=Cnt+1
        Else
           j=j+1
        End If
    End If
Next i
Formula=m
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517946/crystal-reports-error-a-subscript-must-be-between-1-and-size-of-array?rq=1).

When assigning variables, use `:=` instead of `=`, and see if that solves your problem.